# Cannot read property of 'load' undefined error

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am working with the google drive API and am simply trying to load in the library when I get the error.

```
function loadDriveApi(){
    gapi.client.load('drive','v3',setMeta())
}
```

that is the load function which i got from the documentation. This is called by an addlistener

```
<script>document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',loadDriveApi())</script>
```

and the loadDriveApi calls this function eventually.

```
function setMeta(){
    var body={'contentHints.indexableText': document.getElementById('drop')}
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.update({
        'fileId': document.getElementById('doc_id').value,
        'resource': body
    });
    request.execute(function(resp){
        console.log('Copy ID: ' + resp.id); 
    })  
}
```

This is driving me crazy and it's probably something so small and dumb that will end up being the issue but if you have any suggestions i'd love to hear them. I'm also quite the rookie with javascript so that could be why

Thanks

Comment: You probably want `document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',loadDriveApi)` - that is, *without* the `()` that's currently calling your function instead of passing it to `addEventListener()`.

Comment: ... what pointy said, and also `gapi.client.load('drive','v3', setMeta)`

Comment: I have stopped getting the error, I got rid of the brackets, thanks guys! Now onto the next error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gapi.client is probably null or undefined. If it is, no properties will exist, so you'll get a undefined property error.

Make sure the Google Drive API JavaScript dependency is fully loaded before loadDriveApi() is called.

Also, you should be passing the loadDriveApi function to the addEventListener method, not the result of calling loadDriveApi.

For example:

```
<script>document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',loadDriveApi())</script>
```

should be

```
<script>document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', loadDriveApi)</script>
```

The same applies to the gapi.client.load function:

```
gapi.client.load('drive','v3',setMeta())
```

should be

```
gapi.client.load('drive','v3',setMeta)
```

Comment: So how would I know if the Drive API is fully loaded before the function is called?

Comment: It depends how you load it into the page. You could add an onload listener to the script tag that loads it, either manually by adding the onload attribute to the script tag or, better, programmatically. 

Is there a reason you're not using jQuery or a similar library to find elements in the DOM and to manage your event handlers? 

jQuery's getScript method will load the script and call a callback function when it's done loading. You can do your check in the callback or set a flag variable which you could use later to check that the load is done. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript

Comment: I got it working, the API was fully loaded just the code that the drive uses is dumb and the documentation isn't as clear as i wish it was. But i really appreciate the help thanks so much!